# Update Date field with the value of custom label in Process builder

Tags: process-builder, date, field-update, customlabel

I want to update Date field with the value of custom label in Process builder.
I am trying to do like

```
DATE($Label.NYResident_ExpDate)
```

custom label value is 2016-01-31
Please suggest what needs to be done..

Comment: yes that is correct way what is the issue you are facing

Comment: date field value is set to blank

Comment: I tested it in my org and working correctly. Is the date firld or datetime field that you are updating?

Comment: sorry, earlier I was using DATE function. It is working fine with DATEVALUE. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work for `DATE($Label.NYResident_ExpDate)`

I have used DATEVALUE function like shown below

```
 DATEVALUE($Label.NYResident_ExpDate)
```

and its working fine.